# Python : Split Amount into Thousands and Lakhs

Tags: python, split, integer

i have an Amount Object which an Integer that i want to split into Lakhs and Thousands. So for Example say the `amount = 2,50,000` i want to split this into `lakhs = 2,00,000` and `thousands = 50,000`.

Currently i am using the following method.

```
def split_amount(value):
    """ A custom method to Split amount into Lakhs and Thousands """
    tho, lak = 0, 0
    digits = list(str(value))

    if len(digits) < 4:
        print 'Error :  Amount to small to split'
    elif len(digits) == 4:
        tho = ('').join(digits[-4:])
    elif len(digits) == 5:
        tho = ('').join(digits[-5:])
    elif len(digits) == 6:
        tho = ('').join(digits[-5:])
        lak = ('').join(digits[-6:])
    elif len(digits) >= 7:
        tho = ('').join(digits[-5:])
        lak = ('').join(digits[-7:])
    else:
        print "Error : Unknown Error"

    if int(tho) <= 0:
        thousands = 0 
    else:
        thousands = int(tho)

    if (int(lak) - int(tho) <= 0): 
        lakhs = 0 
    else:
        lakhs = int(lak) - int(tho)

    return (lakhs, thousands)
```

This code looks ugly and i am sure there is a better and a shorter way around. Could you help me achieve what i want in a better way ?

Comment: can you show some sample input-outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, why don't you just use the modulus operator?

```
amount = 250000

thousands = amount % 100000
lakhs = amount - thousands
```